# How to make the app go to another page if it is not run by first time

Tags: android, button, sharedpreferences

I have `RegisterPage` and `LoginPage`. When the app is run, it will check whether the app is first time run or not in `RegisterPage`. If it is first time run and the save `button` is not clicked, it will in `RegisterPage`. If it is run second times but the save button is never clicked, it will remain in `RegisterPage` too. Otherwise it will go to `LoginPage`.

Here my updated code

**Register**

```
appGetFirstTimeRun();
boolean clicked=false;

 buttonSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                clicked=true;
                int appCurrentBuildVersion = BuildConfig.VERSION_CODE;
                SharedPreferences appPreferences = getSharedPreferences("MyAPP", 0);
                appPreferences.edit().putInt("app_second_time",
                        appCurrentBuildVersion).apply();
                String name = editTextName.getText().toString();
                String pass = editTextPassword.getText().toString();
                String confirm = editTextConfirm.getText().toString();
                if ((editTextName.getText().toString().trim().length() == 0) || (editTextPassword.getText().toString().trim().length() == 0) || (editTextConfirm.getText().toString().trim().length() == 0)) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Field cannot be null", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } 
                else
                 {
                      insertData(name, pass, imageUri); // insert to SQLite
                      Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AddMonthlyExpenses.class);
                      intent.putExtra("name", name);
                      startActivity(intent);
                  }
            }
        });

  private int appGetFirstTimeRun() {

        //Check if App Start First Time
        SharedPreferences appPreferences = getSharedPreferences("MyAPP", 0);
        int appCurrentBuildVersion = BuildConfig.VERSION_CODE;
        int appLastBuildVersion = appPreferences.getInt("app_first_time", 0);

        if (appLastBuildVersion == appCurrentBuildVersion && clicked) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,LoginPage.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            return 1;
        } else {
            appPreferences.edit().putInt("app_first_time",
                    appCurrentBuildVersion).apply();
            if (appLastBuildVersion == 0) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "First time", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return 0; //es la primera vez
            } else {
                return 2; //es una versión nueva
            }
        }
    }
```

The problem is when I click the save button and exit from the app. When I run the app again it still in the RegisterPage, not in LoginPage.

Comment: clicked variable is always false when your appGetFirstTimeRun(); is called

Comment: @TabishHussain what is the correct way to do that

Comment: instead of using clicked in that function try to check if the data is inserted in the Database by querying the data.. So if data exist then move it to the Login Page

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check button click after inserting data into SQLite, So you can confirm that your data has successfully saved and you can proceed to next screen.

Find my comments in below code and edit your code:-

```
public class Register extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button buttonSave;
    boolean clicked=false;//remove this
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);
        appGetFirstTimeRun();//call this method here
        buttonSave=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
        buttonSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                clicked=true;//remove this
                int appCurrentBuildVersion = BuildConfig.VERSION_CODE;
                SharedPreferences appPreferences = getSharedPreferences("MyAPP", 0);
                appPreferences.edit().putInt("app_second_time", appCurrentBuildVersion).apply();

                String name = editTextName.getText().toString();
                String pass = editTextPassword.getText().toString();
                String confirm = editTextConfirm.getText().toString();
                if ((editTextName.getText().toString().trim().length() == 0) || (editTextPassword.getText().toString().trim().length() == 0) || (editTextConfirm.getText().toString().trim().length() == 0)) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Field cannot be null", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                else
                {
                    insertData(name, pass, imageUri); // insert to SQLite
                    appPreferences.edit().putBoolean("btn_clicked", true).apply();//add this line
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Register.this, AddMonthlyExpenses.class);
                    intent.putExtra("name", name);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            }
        });
    }
    private int appGetFirstTimeRun() {

        //Check if App Start First Time
        SharedPreferences appPreferences = getSharedPreferences("MyAPP", 0);
        int appCurrentBuildVersion = BuildConfig.VERSION_CODE;
        int appLastBuildVersion = appPreferences.getInt("app_first_time", 0);
        boolean is_btn_click=appPreferences.getBoolean("btn_clicked",false);//add this line

        if ((appLastBuildVersion == appCurrentBuildVersion) && is_btn_click) { //edit this line like this
            Intent intent = new Intent(Register.this,LoginPage.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            return 1;
        } else {
            appPreferences.edit().putInt("app_first_time",
                    appCurrentBuildVersion).apply();
            if (appLastBuildVersion == 0) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "First time", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return 0; //es la primera vez
            } else {
                return 2; //es una versión nueva
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

you are depending on `SharedPreferences` as well as on `clicked` variable, you can depend on `SharePreferences` but not on variable because on each run you are setting clicked value to false.

1) Save current version in preference when button is clicked

```
appPreferences.edit().putInt("app_first_time",
                appCurrentBuildVersion).apply();
```

2) save clicked value in preference when button is clicked

```
appPreferences.edit().putBoolean("clicked",
                true).apply();
```

Now inside your `appGetFirstTimeRun()` fetch the value of version and clicked from `SharedPreferences`

```
int appLastBuildVersion = appPreferences.getInt("app_first_time", 0);
boolean clicked = appPreferences.getBoolean("clicked", false);
```

Answer (score 2):

You also need to change the shared preferences value on click of save button. Then only next time when you open the app appGetFirstTimeRun method will load the Login page.

In you btnSave click listener where you are starting intent for activity just before startActivity add this code

```
int appCurrentBuildVersion = BuildConfig.VERSION_CODE;
    SharedPreferences appPreferences = getSharedPreferences("MyAPP", 0);

   appPreferences.edit().putInt("app_first_time",
                appCurrentBuildVersion).apply();
```

Comment: How to change the shared preferences value?

Comment: do you have any idea ?

Answer (score 1):

in ***start*** of `onCreate();` method, call `checkStages();`

in ***end*** of `buttonSave.onClick()` method, call `Prefs.putStage(this, 1);` followed by `checkStages();`

```
/*Prefs.getStage(this) default value is 0*/

public void checkStages() {

    switch(Prefs.getStage(this)) {
        case 1: //Login Page
            startActivity(new Intent(this, LoginPage.class));
            finish();
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

---

This is the sample **[Android Application Template](https://github.com/shanraisshan/Android-Copy-Database/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/adt/Main.java)** I use, to write any of my Android App.

You can get the ***Prefs*** class from this project

Answer (score 0):

add this code to your splash screen

```
 SharedPreferences wmbPreference = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    boolean isFirstRun = wmbPreference.getBoolean("FIRSTRUN", false);
    if (!isFirstRun) {
startActivity(new Intent(context,RegirstorActivity.class));
}else{
startActivity(new Intent(context,LoginActivty.class));
}
```

so basically it will decide Is it first time (user registered) or not, after registration update the SharedPreferences

Comment: but I don't want to have splash screen in my app

Comment: one approach is in your register screen directly check in onCreate if user is already register go to login screen else stay on register screen

Answer (score 0):

your are using click variable to identify if button is clicked or not but when you exist from the app and again then click value reset to false so instead of saving value in click variable you can use shared preference to save value true or false on button click and get value from shared preference to check

on click of save button

```
   appPreferences.edit().putInt("app_second_time",
                    appCurrentBuildVersion).apply();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this may be the answer. on your code `clicked boolean` variable is not stored on shared preferences but you are checking condition inside appGetFirstTimeRun() (button may not be clicked at second launch, but your condition needs to be true) so change your code by
Adding this line `appPreferences.edit().putBoolean("first_run", true).apply();`on  `buttonSave` clicklistener and then add this line `clicked = appPreferences.getBoolean("first_run", false);`on `appGetFirstTimeRun()` function
and the complete code would be.

```
appGetFirstTimeRun();
boolean clicked=false;

 buttonSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                int appCurrentBuildVersion = BuildConfig.VERSION_CODE;
                SharedPreferences appPreferences = getSharedPreferences("MyAPP", 0);
                appPreferences = appPreferences.edit().putBoolean("first_run",
                true).apply(); //***Add this ****
                appPreferences.edit().putInt("app_second_time",
                        appCurrentBuildVersion).apply();
                String name = editTextName.getText().toString();
                String pass = editTextPassword.getText().toString();
                String confirm = editTextConfirm.getText().toString();
                if ((editTextName.getText().toString().trim().length() == 0) || (editTextPassword.getText().toString().trim().length() == 0) || (editTextConfirm.getText().toString().trim().length() == 0)) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Field cannot be null", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } 
                else
                 {
                      insertData(name, pass, imageUri); // insert to SQLite
                      Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AddMonthlyExpenses.class);
                      intent.putExtra("name", name);
                      startActivity(intent);
                  }
            }
        });

  private int appGetFirstTimeRun() {

        //Check if App Start First Time
        SharedPreferences appPreferences = getSharedPreferences("MyAPP", 0);
        int appCurrentBuildVersion = BuildConfig.VERSION_CODE;
        int appLastBuildVersion = appPreferences.getInt("app_first_time", 0);
        clicked = appPreferences.getBoolean("first_run", false); //*** Add this ***
        if (appLastBuildVersion == appCurrentBuildVersion && clicked) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,LoginPage.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            return 1;
        } else {
            appPreferences.edit().putInt("app_first_time",
                    appCurrentBuildVersion).apply();
            if (appLastBuildVersion == 0) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "First time", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return 0; //es la primera vez
            } else {
                return 2; //es una versión nueva
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: The problem is that if I never click the save button in register and launch the app second time, it will goes to login. I want it make sure the save button is clicked, then only go to login

Answer (score 0):

Try using following  custom getter and setter method.

```
private static SharedPreferences getInstance(Context context) {
    context.getSharedPreferences("MY_APP", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    return sharedPreferences;
}

public boolean getAppStatus(Context context) {
    return getInstance(context).getString("FIRST_TIME", false);
}

public void setAppStatus(Context context, boolean status) {
    getInstance(context).edit().putString("FIRST_TIME", status).commit();
}
```

Now, When for the first time when you call getAppStatus() or in case where user haven't clicked save button even once. It will return false. You can update the value of "FIRST_TIME" variable when the user clicks on save button to true. Thus validating, whether user has interacted with register page or not.

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if(v.getId()==R.id.save_button)
     setAppStatus(context,true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    //Use shared preference to save.
SharedPreferences preferedName=getSharedPreferences("firstrun", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferedName.edit();
                editor.putboolean("firstrun",value);
                editor.apply();
                editor.commit();
//and to retrive.
SharedPreferences preferedName=getSharedPreferences("firstrun", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
        boolean rstate =preferedName.getString("firstrun",false);
```

check if "rstste" is false show register page else show the login page.